# how to create uwsgi mulefunc handler?

Tags: python, uwsgi

The uwsgi documentation states that adding *uwsgidecorators.mulefunc* decorator to any function will offload function call to mule. 
The default mule(without a brain) does not execute actual function and just show messages like this:

```
*** mule 1 received a 97 bytes message ***
```

However digging into the code shows that there is a *uwsgi.mule_msg_hook* function which is for handling offloaded calls(BTW nothing in documentation about *mule_msg_hook*).
And by giving a simple brain to mule like this:

```
while True:
    uwsgi.mule_msg_hook(uwsgi.mule_get_msg())
```

Will solve the problem.

But there is one place in source code of uwsgi(https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mule_msg_hook  file **plugins/python/python_plugin.c** ) where *mule_msg_hook* is called. So I'm guessing that there exists another way to handle **mulefuncs** without using non-documented funcitons, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Check

https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/uwsgidecorators.py#L165

it should clarify how the trick works.

Just ensure to load the module with the decorated function in the master (--lazy-apps will not work, unless you load the module specifically in the master via --shared-pyimport)

Comment: Thanks, I already checked that part of code and then found out about "mule_msg_hook" function, as I couldn't find anything in the documentations.